# Efficient way for converting list of dictionary to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I'm trying to convert a list of dictionary (nested dictionary) into a pandas dataframe. Since my file is too long (approx 200k elements of dictionary), So I need an efficient way to convert it into a pandas dataframe.

What i tried:

1. Converting the dictionary into json file (Taking too much time)

   ```
   for d in dict_list:
       with open('data.json','a') as fp:
           json.dump(d,fp)
   ```
2. Converting directly to pandas dataframe

   ```
   for d in dict_list:
       df = pandas.DataFrame(d, index=[0])    #Got from stackoverflow itself.
   ```

Can anyone suggest some efficient way to handle this?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)` will it help you ?

Comment: One dataframe per dictionary, or one row of a frame per dictionary?

Comment: you probably simple can use `df = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)`. you might have to process it further depending on dict structure

Comment: You might be able to use `pd.io.json.json_normalize`. If you need a solution, please provide a sample input and expected output.

Comment: @MohamedThasinah, I tried that but it's producing following error:- ValueErro: Mixing dicts with non-series may lead to ambiguous ordering. I think it's due to the nested nature of my dictionary

Comment: following error? can you print dict_list structure?

Comment: This is how my one element of the dict list look like-    _{"source":{"id":1234,"name":"something","subnet":"some value"}, "data":{"id1":1234567,"id2":23523,"id3":67345,"sig":{"id":198654,"name":"some name"},"src_ip":"value", "dst_ip":"value1","port":value2}}_ . So the list is like [{},{},{}..........2lakhs times]

Comment: @thushv89, I just provided one sample example of my dictionary and their list. Will it help you to understand my problem? As` json.dumps()` is also taking long time to process, Will `pd.io.json.json_normalize` works without jsonifying data.

Comment: @luigigi,One row of the frame per dictionary.